# Using Difflib SequenceMatcher with Tf-IDF ( TfidfVectorizer)

Tags: python, tf-idf, difflib

I am new to python, so please excuse my naivety. I have researched so many examples of using Cosine similarity to calculate string similarity in Python. I however would like to use Difflib's `SequenceMatcher`. Is there a way to use `TfidfVectorizer` with Difflib's `SequenceMatcher` to calculate similarity score?

Just to give a bit more intro, I have a database of over 6000 comments and suggestions. My goal is to match every incoming submission to all existing suggestions and select the best 5 to 10 suggestions that best matches the new one. I am using `TfidfVectorizer` from `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`